# Formating a german date cause unconverted data remains:am

Tags: python, pandas, setlocale

I have a string `"Mai 2, 2018 6:35:52 AM"`.

I set the local to german (only one i can get to work is deu_deu)
when trying to then format I get the data remains error.

```
import pandas as pd
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'deu_deu')

input_file_path = 'C:\\Users\\xxx'

customer_file_path = pd.read_csv(input_file_path,sep='\t', warn_bad_lines=True, error_bad_lines=False)
customer_file_path['RECEIVED_DATE'] = customer_file_path['RECEIVED_DATE'].str.replace(',', '')
customer_file_path['RECEIVED_DATE'] = customer_file_path['RECEIVED_DATE'].str.replace('AM', 'am')
customer_file_path['RECEIVED_DATE'] = customer_file_path['RECEIVED_DATE'].str.replace('PM', 'pm')
customer_file_path['RECEIVED_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(customer_file_path['RECEIVED_DATE'] ,format='%b %d %Y %I:%M:%S %p')
customer_file_path['RECEIVED_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(customer_file_path['RECEIVED_DATE'] ,format='%b %d %Y %I:%M:%S %p').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Either one fails with the same message:

```
getlocale returns 
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'deu_deu')
Out[167]: 'German_Germany.1252'
```

Comment: I have no trouble parsing the date on ``'de_DE'`` locale. ``deu_deu`` is not a valid locale for me. Can you give a reproducible example?

Comment: de_DE gives me unsupportable locale setting, I am based in USA. Not sure what I can give you to make it reproducible if its working for you?

Comment: Reason I am asking is that I haven't found ``deu_deu`` as a valid locale in *any* reference. All common german locales are of the form ``de_*``. If you are on a UNIX machine, does ``locale -a`` show any of them?

Comment: Hi I am on a windows machine alias shows 
 'de_be': 'de_BE.ISO8859-1',
 'de_ch': 'de_CH.ISO8859-1',
 'de_de': 'de_DE.ISO8859-1',
 'de_li.utf8': 'de_LI.UTF-8', but doesnt work (unsupported setting. deu_deu or German_germany work with 
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'deu_deu')
Out[247]: 'German_Germany.1252'